# Update C# Programs Check with FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to create a program that checks my FTP server version.txt for updates. It will see if the Version.txt has a version that is greater than the current version program then lead them to a site to update.

ex:

version.txt contains 2.0.0.1
Program version is 2.0.0.0

```
public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);

                string v1 = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
                string v2 = "ftp://username:password@servername.bplaced.net/version.txt";

                var version1 = new Version(v1);
                var version2 = new Version(v2);

                var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    //
                }
                else if (result < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is a new version of this program!");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("site.com");
                }

                else
                {
                    //
                }
                return;
            }
```

I get this error with executing

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

[Screenshot of error during Compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnrih.png)

Comment: Storing `"ftp://username:password@servername.bplaced.net/version.txt"` into string variable `v2` is not the same as retrieving that file via FTP and placing the file's contents into the string variable `v2`.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I want it to check the contents of version.txt (which is 2.0.0.1) and the current version is 2.0.0.0. Then lead to the website for them to install the new version.

Comment: Where in your code above is it that you ever retrieve the file being pointed to by `"ftp://username:password@servername.bplaced.net/version.txt"`?

Comment: No? How would I retrieve it so it can be inspected?

Comment: nvm. I found out how. You need to put new WebClient().DownloadString("

Comment: Good luck with your implementation!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put this in front of the FTP server string

```
new WebClient().DownloadString("ftp server string");
```

in this example

```
string v2 = new WebClient().DownloadString("ftp://username:password@servername.bplaced.net/version.txt");
```